# Logout from the main form and show the login form in C#.NET

Tags: c#, winforms

I have designed a pos software.Here is a 3 form one login form,pos_authority form,pos_user form.in pos_authority and pos_user user form have an button for logout.when i click the button i want to logout from the form and want to show the login form.when i login i hide the login form.here is my code

```
    private void blogout_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms)
            {
                if (f.Name != "login_form")
                {
                    f.Close();
                    new login_Form().Show();
                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

here show the exception
Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application.OpenForms is fetching all open forms at runtime, however if you close an open form (which in turn remove it from the OpenForm), the foreach statement will throw you exception saying the collection has been changed, which is true.

to workaround for this kind of problem, you could store the open forms into a list:

```
Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>().ToList()
```

or traverse the collection the other way round - from the last to the first instead.

EDIT:

to get rid of the exception, replace your `foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms)` with `foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>().ToList())`, i did not test it, but it should work in theory.

But i don't think it will function well even if you correct the exception - you will end up with many login form shown if there are more than one opened form. i suggest you review your entire design and try to use event - you know windows forms are event driven!

Comment: where i implement this @ REX.i don't get a proper solution man.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your login form;

```
private void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form aform = new Form();
    aform.Show();
    aform.FormClosing += FrmClosing;
    Hide();
}

private void FrmClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Show();
}
```

Basically, you listen (from the login form) to the form closing event for the other form and when it occurs, you show the login form again. Works a treat for my programs.

Comment: here actually i have one mistake login form show but show the exception Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.I want to remove this exception so help plzzzz.

Comment: You implemented the code I posted and still got the same exception? That doesn't sound right to me...
Try implementing the above code. Or if that's not good for you, then please post the Stack Trace.

Comment: i do this ur code but show the same exception.u tell that i do my code in login form as well as ur code also

Comment: OK, did you get rid of your code? I'm pretty sure the foreach loop is the issue, but with my code you won't need that at all, so remove it all and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Your exception is because you are calling `f.Close()` which deletes de form, changing the collection which is looping in the foreach and thus being unable to continue looping.

And I think you should change your code from:

```
new login_Form().Show();
```

to:

```
login_Form.Show();
```

Comment: if i do this then it can't get login_form.